# Wilcox.test returns two different values for the same data

Tags: r, statistics

I have a df with two groups, A and B.

```
group <- c(A, A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B)
measure <- c(3.4, 2.76, 3.37, 2.66, 2.73, 3.91, 9.06, 4.87, 3.4, 3.01, 1.95, 1.88, 1.85, 1.77, 1.77, 0.95, 0.25)
df <- data.frame(group, measure)
```

If I say

```
wilcox.test(measure ~ group, data = df)
```

I get p = 0.06 (with a warning  about ties and exact values).  However, if I create two vectors A and B with the exact same data

```
 A <- c(3.4, 2.76, 3.37, 2.66, 2.73, 3.91)
 B <- c(9.06, 4.87, 3.4, 3.01, 1.95, 1.88, 1.85, 1.77, 1.77, 0.95, 0.25)
```

and say

```
wilcox.test(A,B, paired = FALSE, alternative = "two.sided")
```

I get p = 0.1908 (same error about ties, I get that).  Neither value is "significant" but the difference is disturbing.  What am I doing wrong?? TIA

Comment: What is the value of `A` and `B` when you create `group <- c(A, A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B)`

Comment: The mean was different for group B, which led me to find a data entry error.  Thanks! They match now.

Answer (score 0):

Can not reproduce the issue.  I think in the first case you are substituting in the variables A & B and not the labels "A" & "B"

```
A <- c(3.4, 2.76, 3.37, 2.66, 2.73, 3.91)
B <- c(9.06, 4.87, 3.4, 3.01, 1.95, 1.88, 1.85, 1.77, 1.77, 0.95, 0.25)
wilcox.test(x=A, y=B)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  A and B
W = 46.5, p-value = 0.1908
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x = A, y = B) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
 

group <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
measure <- c(3.4, 2.76, 3.37, 2.66, 2.73, 3.91, 9.06, 4.87, 3.4, 3.01, 1.95, 1.88, 1.85, 1.77, 1.77, 0.95, 0.25)
df <- data.frame(group, measure)
wilcox.test(measure ~ group, data = df)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  measure by group
W = 46.5, p-value = 0.1908
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x = c(3.4, 2.76, 3.37, 2.66, 2.73, 3.91),  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Comment: thanks for checking - the problem is solved.  there was a data entry error in the actual df.  Once corrected the two calculations now give the same result.